# How to write my Struct to Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, struct

I have this struct:

```
struct Info {
    var name: String = ""
    var number = Int()
}

 var infoProvided : [Info] = []
```

I display desired data in a `tableView`:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InfoCell") as! InfoTableViewCell

         let name = infoProvided[indexPath.row].name
         let number = infoProvided[indexPath.row].number

         cell.infoLabelLabel.text = "\(name) with \(number)"

        return cell
    }
```

I am trying to write data to firebase like this:

```
self.ref?.child(gotLokasjon).child(location).child(dateAndTime).updateChildValues(["Signed up:" : infoProvided])
```

This returns the error:
Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at 0. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

How can I write my Struct to Firebase?. I would like to write it equal to how its displayed in the tableView:

```
 cell.infoLabelLabel.text = "\(name) with \(number)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't understood where you want the upload to happen(before or after they are displayed on tableView) so adjust it to suit your needs.

```
 guard let name  = infoProvided.name else {return}
 guard let number = infoProvided.number else {return}

 let data = [ "name": name, "number": number] as [String : Any]
 self.ref?.child(gotLokasjon).child(location).child(dateAndTime).updateChildValues(data, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                        if error != nil{
                            print(error!)
                            return
                        }
                        print(" Successfully uploaded")
                    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry for being unclear. The data is shown in the tableView, and if that is correct the user presses a button to upload the data. I cannot access the `.name`or `.number`with `guard let name  = infoProvided.name else {return}` Error: Value of type '[infoPovided]' has no member 'name'

Comment: In this case you will have to use  infoProvided[indexPath.row].name

Comment: Great, now its uploading to Firebase. But what if the user puts in more than one name and number? With the above approach it only uploads the last item? Or am I missing something?

Comment: "How can I write my Struct to Firebase?" i have answered your question. For any more questions provide the relevant code and post a new question. If you have found a solution and want some feedback you should post on code review. Iterate through `infoProvided`, use my answer and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of fiddling I did this:

```
let infoArray = infoProvided.map { [$0.number, $0.name] }
 let items = NSArray(array: infoArray)
```

Then implemented that in the above solution. This seams to work.

I don't know if this is a good solution?